# jsonschema expecting allOf to be of type 'object' or 'boolean'

Tags: json, schema, python-jsonschema

I'm using PyPi jsonschema to validate my test schema.

Here are the contents of test_schema.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema#",
  "title": "Single IV Run JSON Schema",
  "description": "Schema for single IV run sequence",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "allOf": [
      { "$ref": "/schemas/test/dut.json"},
      {
        "properties": {
          "IV": {"$ref": "/schemas/test/iv.json"}
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "required": ["IV"]
}
```

Using jsonschema.Draft7Validator.check_schema(test_schema), I receive the following error, even though I copied the general schema structure from the [official draft 7 example](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/william.su/workspaces/speedit_sandbox/schema_parser.py", line 129, in <module>
    Draft7Validator.check_schema(schema)
  File "C:\Users\william.su\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\validators.py", line 294, in check_schema
    raise exceptions.SchemaError.create_from(error)
jsonschema.exceptions.SchemaError: [{'$ref': '/schemas/test/dut.json'}, {'properties': {'IV': {'$ref': '/schemas/test/iv.json'}}}] is not of type 'object', 'boolean'
```